# Xamarin Archive Manager fails with: The specified path, file name, or both are too long

Tags: xamarin.android

When I try to create an archive from Visual Studio to distribute my Xamarin Android App, the Archive Manager fails with the message:

"Failed to create App archive 'MyCompanyName.Client.Droid'.
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Unfortunately the Archive Manager does not tell which file is causing the problem.

I already tried to move the project and the nuget packages to a root folder but this doesn'n help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me quite some time, hope this Q&A will save others this time.

It turned out that the Archive Manager is using quite a long path for the archive.

Because the project name included our long company name, some (fully qualified) file names became too long, like:

```
C:\Users\marcel\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives\2016-12-06\MyLongCompanyName.Client.Droid 12-06-16 12.03 PM.apkarchive\mSYM\com.mylongcompanyname.client.droid.apk.mSYM\11b0326b39654e09a35393ebb19e1b1f\MyLongCompanyName.Client.CachedRepositories.dll.mdb
```

Changing the project name to a short name solved the problem.

Comment: Changing the project name is not a real solution. It's far better to enable `Win32 Long Paths` inside Windows from `Local Group & Policy Editor` as described above by @anonymous

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Windows 10 Anniversary Update, it does not hurt to enable long path inside Windows.

Press Windows key + R to open the Run dialog. Type gpedit.msc.
Navigate to: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem
Double click on "Enable Win32 long paths". Enable it.
Alternatively, if you don't see this option click on NTFS > Enable NTFS long path.
Restart Visual Studio 2017. Done!

[source](http://miaw.xyz/b/post/2017/08/28/the-specified-path-file-name-or-both-are-too-long-while-archiving-xamarin-builds-in-archive-manager)

Comment: Sounds good but doesn't work for me (I even reboot computer) :(

Answer (score 4):

In my case in using Visual Studio 2017, when I saw the error, I just closed Archive Manager. Then when I reopened Archive Manager, the error is gone and I can continue to distribute the package. It works everytime for me, hopefully it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172662/5438626) on StackOverflow that IMO addresses the root issue. It worked for me and I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encountered the same problem
compiling the package is up and running again after deleting all of the items contained in the folder: 
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives

I hope it help you

Andy