# Can't Archive a Xamarin.Forms Application

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build a distribution-ready apk (following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60184629/7825830)) for a project I've been working on recently using Xamarin.Forms and Visual Studio 2019. However, i can't get past the Archiving Stage because i keep getting below error as stated by Visual Studio itself:

```
Cannot create the archive file because the copy of mdbs files failed.
Could not find a part of the path ...
```

[image]

Its worth noting that i have not changed anything yet on the project properties and the solution is stored on a relatively short path of `D:\Repository\QR Code Attendance`. If i am to guess, this is an issue with PATH limited to 255 characters? If so, how would i be able to overcome it?

Just copying the apk from the \Debug Folder and installing it on a Android Phone doesn't work. The app just closes as soon as it starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Archives are not in the solution folder. Your Archives folder is in `C:/User/Administrator/App Data/Local/Xamarin/Mono for Android/Archives`. You shoud change it to something shorter, like `C:/Archives`. This can be done in `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings -> Archives Location`.

Comment: thank you sir, that fixed my rather simple problem.

Comment: Just don't make the same mistake as me: I typed in 'C:\Archives\Android' as the path and hit OK with the confident assumption that it would create the directory. __It does not__. When archiving failed again, I reopened the tool only to find the reverted original path. I recommend using the browse button to set the new path!